# Where does light energy end up?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, absorption

Here's a gedankenexperiment:

In situation A you run $P$ watts of incandescent bulbs in a closed room for time $t$ (light and heat cannot escape the room). The room starts a temperature $T$ and ends at temperature $T_a$ after time $t$.

In situation B you run $P$ watts of LED bulbs in the same room also for time t. The room starts a temperature $T$ and ends at temperature $T_b$ after time $t$.

How does $T_a$ compare to $T_b$?

Comment: Can one assume that the lights are switched off and the rooms are dark before the temperature is measured?

Comment: Can one also assume that the rooms are _closed systems?_ (I.E., assume that none of the heat can ever leave?) And what does "temperature of the room" mean? Can we assume that the temperature is measured only after the light has been switched off, and only after enough time has passed that the air and all of the walls and floor and ceiling have reached the same equillibrium temperature?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "P Watts" here. If "P Watts" is the power requirements of the lighting systems, then each uses the same power and so emits the same energy into the room over the time interval. In this case, the temperatures are the same. If, on the other hand, "P Watts" is the power of the visible light, then the incandescent bulb is drawing much more power than the LED since it is less efficient. In this case, the incandescent bulb heats the room more than the LED.

Note that in the first case, the LED is much brighter than the incandescent bulb, again due to its efficiency. The "extra power" from the incandescent is in the infrared range, so it is still there even though you don't see it.

Answer (score -1):

An incandescent light bulb works by heating a filament(usually titanium) to $\approx 3000 C$. This emits light but $\approx 90$% of the energy is converted to heat and is radiated.

An LED light bulb is very efficient and produces very little heat.

So suppose both the bulbs have power $P$ and are fitted in 2 separate highly insulated rooms. The LED bulb would be very bright at a power consumption that an incandescent bulb requires but the heat radiated by the LED would not be even close to what the incandescent bulb emits.

Hence $T_a > T_b$

Fun Fact : A couple years ago. one of my school mates made a project for the school science fair and it was a dryer which quickly dries small clothes like hand kerchiefs, napkins, socks .etc and they used 2 incandescent bulbs to heat the clothes. Those things produce a ton of heat.

Comment: You are correct in saying that an LED light bulb is much more efficient than an incandescent bulb. It's nore efficient at turning electrical energy into visible light energy, so a 10W LED bulb will look much brighter (about an order of magnitude brigher) than a 10W incandescent bulb. But all of the light (including infrared light) put out by either bulb will heat the walls of the room when it is absorbed. So, in the end, assuming that the room is a closed system, either bulb adds the same 10 Joules of heat to the room in every second when it is switched on.